# Uncertainty in semiprime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

What is maximum $p\in(0,\frac12)$ such that if we know $2p\in(0,1)$ fraction of bits of $PQ$ with $P,Q$ primes it is possible to identify $p$ fraction of bits in each of $P,Q$ with certainty in polynomial time?